# `\seq_item` doesn't work in `cases` environment

Tags: amsmath, expl3, cases, l3seq

I'm trying to create a macro that can dynamically create a `cases` environment.
Unfortunately, there's a problem I cannot quite comprehend.

For some reason, the invocation of `\seq_item` does not produce text when used *after* the `&`-token. Putting other text after the `&`-token or putting `{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}` before `&` produces the expected text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\caseExp}[1]{
\group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq  \l_tmpa_seq {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {##1}
    {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}} & {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}} 
  }
  \begin{cases}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\\}
  \end{cases}
\group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

$
f(x) = \caseExp{{AAAA,BBBB},{CCCC,DDDD}}
$

\end{document}
```

The output of the code is the following, but I would expect seeing `BBBB` and `DDDD` there.

[image]

What's the reason for this puzzling behavior? How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cases` uses alignments internally and each cell forms a group and you're setting a sequence in a group, but trying to use its value in a different one.

You can use a simpler strategy with `\clist_use:nn` which is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\caseExp}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_tmpa_seq  \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \clist_use:nn { ##1 } { & }
   }
  \begin{cases}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\\}
  \end{cases}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
f(x) = \caseExp{{AAAA,BBBB},{CCCC,DDDD}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even avoid the enclosing group, by doing all the work in the first cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\caseExp}{m}
 {
  \begin{cases}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_tmpa_seq  \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \clist_use:nn { ##1 } { & }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\\}
  \end{cases}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
f(x) = \caseExp{{AAAA,BBBB},{CCCC,DDDD}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Indeed, `\seq_use:Nn` will deliver the result “all at once”, so TeX will see `&` and `\\` at a time when preserving the value of `\l_tmpa_seq` is no longer necessary.

Even simpler, exploiting the fact that a trailing `\\` in `cases` is irrelevant (not in `align`, beware):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\caseExp}{m}
 {
  \begin{cases}
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__egreg_cases_row:n
  \end{cases}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_cases_row:n
 {
  \clist_use:nn { #1 } { & } \\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
f(x) = \caseExp{{AAAA,BBBB},{CCCC,DDDD}}
\]

\end{document}
```